# Access Element in Paginated Dictionary. Dictionary within a list. Python 3.6

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary, pagination

I am trying to access and cache (set) the value element in a paginated dictionary. I want each new paginated dictionary to do this. There is a way to go through the dictionaries with "before" and "after" parameters, but I think that might be an unnecessary tidbit.

When I do this:

```
[{x:1,y:2}]
pag_dict = foo.get_dict()
xvalue = bar.set(pag_dict["x"])
print(xvalue)
```

I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" for the line with xvalue = bar.set(pag_dict["x"]). I just need it to print out 1 by accessing x.

I keep running into problems every way I try to fix this. Help would be extremely appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, do you mean your `page_dict = [{x:1,y:2}]` ?

Comment: Yeah, essentially. I put foo.get_dict() because I'm accessing the paginated dictionaries from an API.

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in comment:

```
pag_dict = [[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}]]
```

The above shows `pag_dict` is a `list` of `list` with 1 element. The element is of type Python's `dict`, which is a key-value pairs.

To get value of key `x`, try this:

```
# this gives "1"
pag_dict[0][0]['x']
```

Comment: I still get the same  "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Are you sure this is the case => `pag_dict = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}]` ? If that's true, then `pag_dict[0]['x']` will give `1`. Else you need to check what is `pag_dict`   contains or post more code here.

Comment: I just looked at the response I get back from the API again and it is actually a dictionary within a list within another list.. Which doesn't make any sense to me. It's a [[{}]]. This might have something to do with it.

Comment: If that’s the case, then it has to be like : pag_dict[0][0][‘x’] , where the 0 is the list element index.

Comment: I updated my answer as per discussion. If it helps you in any way, mind to mark it as answer? Thanks.